# Pointer becomes null

Tags: c, memory, fopen

I'm passing a file pointer to a function(A) which then opens the file, reads a line in a while loop (for each line in the file) and calls another function(B) using theses values. The issue is after running through function B once, the file pointer becomes NULL and I'm not sure why.

```
void readMatrixData(matrix *matrix, FILE *fileInput) 
{

    char buffer[30];

    while(fgets(buffer, 30, fileInput) != NULL) {
        char *splitString = strtok(buffer, ",");

        int row = atoi(splitString);
        splitString = strtok(NULL, ",");
        int column = atoi(splitString);
        splitString = strtok(NULL, ",");
        int value = atoi(splitString);

        insertNewNode(&matrix->rowArray[row], &matrix->columnArray[column], value, row, column);
    }
}
```

I check if fopen returns NULL before calling function A, and it's not. I've also set a breakpoint on the while loop and the first time it hits, fileInput has some memory allocated. However, on the second loop fileInput becomes NULL and I'm not sure why.

EDIT:

Here's the insertNewNode function:

```
void insertNewNode(node **rowHead, node **columnHead, int value, int row, int column) {

    //Get to the correct position in the column linked list
    if (*columnHead == NULL) {
        *columnHead = malloc(sizeof(node));
    } else {
        while((*columnHead)->nextColumn != NULL && (*columnHead)->nextColumn->row < row)
            *columnHead = (*columnHead)->nextColumn;
    }

    //Get to the correct position in the row linked list.
    if (*rowHead == NULL) {
        *rowHead = malloc(sizeof(node));
    } else {
        while((*rowHead)->nextRow != NULL && ((*rowHead)->nextRow->column < column))
            *rowHead = (*rowHead)->nextRow;
    }

    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->column = column;
    newNode->row = row;
    newNode->value = value;

    (*columnHead)->nextColumn = newNode;
    (*rowHead)->nextRow = newNode;
}
```

The structs involved are:

```
typedef struct matrix {
    node **rowArray;
    node **columnArray;
Size matrixDimensions;
} matrix;

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    int row;
    int column;
    struct node *nextColumn;
    struct node *nextRow;
} node;
```

and I initialise the matrix arrays with:

```
node *columns[m->matrixDimensions.columns];
node *rows[m->matrixDimensions.rows];

for (int i=0; i< m->matrixDimensions.columns; i++)
{
    columns[i] = NULL;
}

for (int i=0; i < m->matrixDimensions.rows; i++)
{
    rows[i] = NULL;
}

m->columnArray = columns;
m->rowArray = rows;
```

Comment: If you comment out insertNewNode what happens? Probably it's the culprit of some memory mess

Comment: `char buffer[30]` and `fgets(buffer,30,fileInput)`? Where does the `\0` go? Either make `buffer[31]` or `fgets(buffer,29,fileInput);`

Comment: you'll need to show the code for `insertNewNode`.

Comment: @askmish, the 2nd arg to `fgets` includes the null pointer in the count.  see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: @Ashelly: Oh! I almost forgot that. Thanks.

Comment: @sth: Agreed.Thanks.  @OP:Unless you are doing something with the same FILE pointer again, then it might be the voodoo `insertNewNode()` or strtok corrupting the stack?

Comment: I've added some more details about the program. I believe it's a problem in insertNewNode but am struggling to get my head around these double pointers.

Comment: To help you a little, try `ferror()` to check if any error occured on FILE* stream and and check what the `errno` contains. Also, try `clearerr()` before reading the file again, perhaps at the end of while loop.

Comment: I've done some more debugging and it seems like after the strtok line some of the nodes in the arrays become filled with garbage. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer `strtol` over `atoi`.

As @DavideBerra suggested, comment out the call to `insertNewNode` and step through the code to confirm you can make multiple iterations of your `while` loop.

I don't understand how you are initialising your matrix arrays using `m->matrixDimensions.columns` and `m->matrixDimensions.rows`.  Are you using C99 VLAs?

Crank up the warning levels of your compiler and ensure zero-warning compilation.

Comment: I've commented it out and the loop is running fine so it is something in insertNewNode. I am using C99 VLAs and so thought that allocated the array fine?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the function insertNewNode overwrites memory

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize the nextRow and nextColumn fields of your newly allocated node. Doing so should prevent you from at least some trouble. It is strange that you do not get a Segfault.

You are also mixing array and linked list, what could happen if you get "overflowing" values from your file ? I feel like the segfault is not far away from here. Be very careful, your code shows weird concept mixing !

As others had suggested you, comment your insertNewNode call and see if your loop is well performed. If it is, run your program step by step using a debugger. Hope this helps, good luck !

Comment: +1 for completely initializing malloc'd columnHeads and rowHeads

Answer (score 0):

check the value of `row` and `column` before accessing `matrix->rowArray` and `matrix->columnArray` whether these values are less than the array size.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the values row,column may be outside your matrix and thus overwriting memory. Add a check of the values you receive and make sure your matrix is large enough. Remember arrays are zero indexed in C.